# Collapsing all other Recyclerview items when one is expanded

Tags: java, android

I have a well-setup expandable recyclerview. When clicked on any item, it gets expanded to show more details. But I want a change here. When one item is clicked to expand, all other items should be collapsed. Here's my adapter code:

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<ListItem> android_versions;
    private List<ListItem> listItems;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Animation animationUp, animationDown;
    private Context context;
    private final int COUNTDOWN_RUNNING_TIME = 500;
    int i =0;

    public DataAdapter(Context context, java.util.List<ListItem> android_versions,
                       Animation animationUp, Animation animationDown) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listItems = android_versions;
        this.animationDown = animationDown;
        this.animationUp = animationUp;
    }

    @Override
    public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    public String getRandomColor(int a){
        String colors[] = {"#ef5350","#f44336","#ef5350"};
        return colors[a];
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int i) {
        ListItem listItem = listItems.get(i);
        if (i%2==2)
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(getRandomColor(0)));
        else if (i%2==1)
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(getRandomColor(1)));
        else if (i%2==0)
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(getRandomColor(2)));

        holder.tv_android.setText(listItem.getSubName());
        holder.contentLayout.setText(listItem.getContent());
        holder.expandit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (holder.contentLayout.isShown()) {
                    holder.contentLayout.startAnimation(animationUp);
                    CountDownTimer countDownTimerStatic = new CountDownTimer(COUNTDOWN_RUNNING_TIME, 16) {
                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish() {
                            holder.contentLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    };
                    countDownTimerStatic.start();
                } else {
                    holder.contentLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.contentLayout.startAnimation(animationDown);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView tv_android;
        private TextView contentLayout;
        RelativeLayout expandit;
        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            tv_android = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_android);
            contentLayout = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content);
            expandit = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.expandit);
        }
    }
}
```

I think it's not possible to change viewHolder's content by position. So how can I hide all other items' content by position. I don't think other code is required so I haven't included it.

Edit: Code after Ashish's suggestion:

```
  private void changeStateOfItemsInLayout(ListItem listItem) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listItems.size(); i++) {
            if (listItems.get(i) == listItem)
                listItem.setShouldBeExpanded(true);
            else
                listItem.setShouldBeExpanded(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int i) {
        ListItem listItem = listItems.get(i);
        if (i%2==2)
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(getRandomColor(0)));
        else if (i%2==1)
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(getRandomColor(1)));
        else if (i%2==0)
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(getRandomColor(2)));

        holder.tv_android.setText(listItem.getSubName());
        holder.contentLayout.setText(listItem.getContent());
        if(listItem.getShouldBeExpanded()){
            holder.contentLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.contentLayout.startAnimation(animationDown);
        }else{
            holder.contentLayout.startAnimation(animationUp);
            CountDownTimer countDownTimerStatic = new CountDownTimer(COUNTDOWN_RUNNING_TIME, 16) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    holder.contentLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            };
            countDownTimerStatic.start();
        }

        holder.expandit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (holder.contentLayout.isShown()) {
                    holder.contentLayout.startAnimation(animationUp);
                    CountDownTimer countDownTimerStatic = new CountDownTimer(COUNTDOWN_RUNNING_TIME, 16) {
                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish() {
                            holder.contentLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    };
                    countDownTimerStatic.start();
                } else {
                    holder.contentLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.contentLayout.startAnimation(animationDown);
                }
                listItems.get(holder.getLayoutPosition()).setShouldBeExpanded(true);
                changeStateOfItemsInLayout(listItems.get(holder.getLayoutPosition()));
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
```

Although in the onClick, I still have the code to expand/collapse layout, even if I remove it, it doesn't work.

Here's my modal class if required:

```
public class ListItem {

    private String subName;
    private String content;
    private String param;
    private Boolean shouldBeExpanded=false;

    public Boolean getShouldBeExpanded() {
        return shouldBeExpanded;
    }

    public void setShouldBeExpanded(Boolean shouldBeExpanded) {
        this.shouldBeExpanded = shouldBeExpanded;
    }

    public ListItem(String subName, String content) {
        this.subName = subName;
        this.content = content;
        this.param = "Nothing";
    }

    public String getParam() {
        return param;
    }

    public ListItem(String subName, String content, String param) {

        this.subName = subName;
        this.content = content;
        this.param = param;
    }

    public String getSubName() {
        return subName;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** As requested, here's the code for animationUp file and animationDown file:

animationUp.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" >

    <scale
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.0" />

</set>
```

animationDown.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <scale
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" />

</set>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Ashish, I solved the problem with a simple logic. Here's my redefined *changeStateOfItemsInLayout* function code:

```
private void changeStateOfItemsInLayout(ListItem listItem, int p) {
        for (int x = 0; x < listItems.size(); x++) {
            if (x == p) {
                listItem.setShouldBeExpanded(true);
                //Since this is the tapped item, we will skip
                //the rest of loop for this item and set it expanded
                continue;
            }
            listItems.get(x).setShouldBeExpanded(false);
        }
    }
```

This function is responsible for collapsing all other items. It checks which option is tapped and expands it (If already expanded, we won't call this function from OnBindViewHolder function) and collapses all others.

Here's my full adapter code:

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<ListItem> android_versions;
    private List<ListItem> listItems;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Animation animationUp, animationDown;
    private Context context;
    private final int COUNTDOWN_RUNNING_TIME = 300;

    public DataAdapter(Context context, java.util.List<ListItem> android_versions,
                       Animation animationUp, Animation animationDown) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listItems = android_versions;
        this.animationDown = animationDown;
        this.animationUp = animationUp;
    }

    @Override
    public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    public String getRandomColor(int a){
        String colors[] = {"#ef5350","#f44336","#ef5350"};
        return colors[a];
    }

    private void changeStateOfItemsInLayout(ListItem listItem, int p) {
        for (int x = 0; x < listItems.size(); x++) {
            if (x == p) {
                listItem.setShouldBeExpanded(true);
                //Since this is the tapped item, we will skip
                //the rest of loop for this item and set it expanded
                continue;
            }
            listItems.get(x).setShouldBeExpanded(false);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int i) {
        ListItem listItem = listItems.get(i);
        if (i%2==2)
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(getRandomColor(0)));
        else if (i%2==1)
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(getRandomColor(1)));
        else if (i%2==0)
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(getRandomColor(2)));

        holder.tv_android.setText(listItem.getSubName());
        holder.contentLayout.setText(listItem.getContent());
        if(listItem.getShouldBeExpanded()){
            holder.contentLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.contentLayout.startAnimation(animationDown);
        }else{
            holder.contentLayout.startAnimation(animationUp);
            CountDownTimer countDownTimerStatic = new CountDownTimer(COUNTDOWN_RUNNING_TIME, 16) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    holder.contentLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            };
            countDownTimerStatic.start();
        }

        holder.expandit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (holder.contentLayout.isShown()) {
                    listItems.get(holder.getLayoutPosition()).setShouldBeExpanded(false);
                } else {
                    listItems.get(holder.getLayoutPosition()).setShouldBeExpanded(true);
                    changeStateOfItemsInLayout(listItems.get(holder.getLayoutPosition()),holder.getLayoutPosition());
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView tv_android;
        private TextView contentLayout;
        RelativeLayout expandit;
        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            tv_android = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_android);
            contentLayout = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content);
            expandit = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.expandit);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide the animationUp and animationDown code?

Comment: @Fathimakm I have edited the post to add your code. Please check!

Answer (score 2):

In your ListItem class which i am assuming is the model class, add a new boolean variable shouldBeExpanded and set its default value to false, and write its getter and setter. Now in your adapter, in onBindViewHolder write the following code

```
if(listItem.shouldBeExpanded()){
//write your code to expand it
}else{
//write the code to collapse
}
```

Now in the code section, in some onClick which expands the layout, set this variable for this lisItem to be true and call a function which sets all other items in the listItem to false for shouldBeExpanded..somewhat by calling the below function changeStateOfItemsInLayout(listItem).
Now called notifiyDataSetChanged().

```
private void changeStateOfItemsInLayout(ListItem listItem){
for(int i=0;i<listItems.size();i++){
if(listItems.get(i)==listItem)
listItem.get(i).setShouldBeExpanded(true);
}else{
listItem.get(i).setShouldBeExpanded(false);
}
}
```

This should solve your purpose.

Comment: Didn't work for me. When I tap an item, it expands for a short while and collapses right away except only for the last item.

Comment: There was a problem. I had been using listItem as final. But removed the final keyword. Still problem persists.

Comment: I dont still see it

Comment: Just above onBindViewHolder function

Comment: can you debug and see if the values of shouldBeExpanded is true for the correct list item and false for ther others after you call notifyDataSetChanges().

Comment: I redefined the logic and it's working now :) I have posted the whole code as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a few hours fiddling with the ExpandableRecyclerAdapter code. But it's really very simple. In your activity you have listeners for expand/collapse events with the current parent list item position being expanded/collapsed. Keep track of the currentExpandedPosition and call the adapter collapseParent to collapse the previously expanded item. A perfect accordion effect in 5 lines of code.

```
private currentExpandedPosition = -1;

        mAdapter.setExpandCollapseListener(new ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.ExpandCollapseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onListItemExpanded(int position) {

            if (currentExpandedPosition >= 0){
                mAdapter.collapseParent(currentExpandedPosition);
            }
            currentExpandedPosition = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onListItemCollapsed(int position) {

           currentExpandedPosition = -1;
        }
    });
```