# (KOTLIN) Expanding and Collapsing in Expandable recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

## Objective

I want to expand new items in a RecyclerView at the same time, and the old selected items will be automatically collapsed.

#### What I done, it can be like this >>

The items expand and collapse on click but do not automatically collapse if another item is expanded

[image1](https://therubberduckdev.files.wordpress.com/2017/10/android-expandable-recyclerview.gif?w=576&h=1024)

#### Actually, what I want to make it like this >>

Any expanded item should be automatically collapse when another item is expanded.

[image2](https://github.com/Artenes/recycler-view-expand-collapse/blob/master/images/oneatime.gif?raw=true)

## What I had researched

1. From this [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27203817/recyclerview-expand-collapse-items) had done what I want, but **I don't how to convert into Kotlin**, basically as I know it store the previous position then compare to the current position, through the If-Else Statement to determine and perform the action.
2. There are one more [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44785206/collapsing-all-other-recyclerview-items-when-one-is-expanded), it also from java, slightly understand, briefly know the whole concept, but cannot go deeply explain for myself line-by-line.
3. This [Github Sample](https://github.com/Artenes/recycler-view-expand-collapse) is pretty matched my needs, but code styling quite complicated, and not fexible enough for me to add other feature and design.

## Question

1. Why the `previousPosition` need to be `-1`?
2. How should separate `currentPosition` and `previousPosition`, and store the `previousPosition` to different object and value?
3. If the `previousPosition` is workable, how should I implement into my project?
4. If available, can share any related resources to me? 
    *like: screen shot the part of sample code, or other resources*

## Code

#### product_list_item.kt

```
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
import org.json.JSONArray
import org.json.JSONObject

class ViewPartActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var newRecylerview : RecyclerView
    private lateinit var newArrayList : ArrayList<Product>
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_part)
        val btnInsertView: FloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.btnInsertView)
        btnInsertView.setOnClickListener {
            val insertViewIntent = Intent(this, AddPartActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(insertViewIntent)
        }
        getData()
    }

    private fun getData() {
        val url = "WEBAPI"
        val requestQueue: RequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        val jsonObjectRequest: JsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            { response ->
                val jsonArray: JSONArray = response.getJSONArray("tbl_product")
                val namelist = ArrayList<String>()
                val categorylist = ArrayList<String>()
                val quantitylist = ArrayList<String>()
                val pricelist = ArrayList<String>()

                for (x in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
                    val jsonObject: JSONObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(x)
                    val name: String = jsonObject.getString("NAME")
                    val category: String = jsonObject.getString("CATOGORYID")
                    val quantity: String = jsonObject.getString("QUANTITY")
                    val price: String = jsonObject.getString("PRICE")

                    namelist.add(name)
                    categorylist.add(category)
                    quantitylist.add(quantity)
                    pricelist.add(price)
                }
                newRecylerview =findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
                newRecylerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
                newRecylerview.setHasFixedSize(true)
                newArrayList = arrayListOf<Product>()
                for(i in namelist.indices){
                    val product = Product(namelist[i],categorylist[i],quantitylist[i],pricelist[i])
                    newArrayList.add(product)
                }

                val adapter = ProductAdapter(newArrayList)
                newRecylerview.adapter = adapter
            }, { error ->
                Toast.makeText(this, error.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            })
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest)
    }
}
```

#### ProductAdapter.kt

```
class ProductAdapter(private val productList : ArrayList<Product>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.product_list_item, parent,false)
        return MyViewHolder(itemView)
    }


    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = productList[position]

        holder.tvProductName.text = currentItem.name
        holder.tvProductCategory.text= currentItem.category
        holder.tvProductQuantity.text=currentItem.quantity
        holder.tvProductPrice.text= "RM "+currentItem.price

        val isVisible : Boolean = currentItem.visibility
        holder.constraintLayout.visibility = if (isVisible) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE

        holder.tvProductName.setOnClickListener{
            currentItem.visibility =!currentItem.visibility
            notifyItemChanged(position)
        }
    }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return productList.size
    }
    class MyViewHolder(itemView : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val tvProductName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productName)
        val tvProductCategory : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productCategory)
        val tvProductQuantity : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productQuantity)
        val tvProductPrice : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productPrice)
        val constraintLayout : ConstraintLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.expandedLayout)
    }
}
```

#### Product.kt

```
data class Product(
    var name: String, var category: String, var quantity: String, var price: String, var visibility: Boolean = false
)
```

## Promise

- Once I get the solution, I would try my best to explain the code more deeply and update at here.

Comment: https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view You can check out this library and programmatically collapse all other group when one is clicked.

Comment: You said you didn't know how to convert to kotlin. Paste Java Code in .kt file. Android Studio will do the conversion. MAGIC!!

Comment: I think it cannot work, some of the code it convert not accurately. The more that I debugged, the more I get confused.